# Problems using opendir() in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, opendir

While testing a class in phpUnit, it throws this error:

```
1) TableTest::testGetTableInputForm
opendir(./views/img/tables): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

The file is accessible and the class is working in production.

If I call opendir() directly inside the testclass, it will throw the same error. If i feed the absolute path to opendir() the test in phpunit will freeze.

This behavior also shows running the test as root.

Is it even possible to test opendir() with phpunit?

phpunit config:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/3.7/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="false"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="false"
         checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="false"
         bootstrap="/external_data/jenkins/jenkins-home/jobs/admin/workspace/test/bootstrap.php"
         cacheTokens="false"
         colors="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         forceCoversAnnotation="false"
         mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
         printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         testSuiteLoaderFile="phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php"
         timeoutForSmallTests="1"
         timeoutForMediumTests="10"
         timeoutForLargeTests="60"
         strict="true"
         verbose="true"
```

Comment: the current folder is the one from which you ran phpunit (unless a chdir has been invoked inside the tests)...

Maybe the relative path is not the one you thought? I would do a `var_dump(realpath("."));` to see what the script thinks the current path is...

Comment: var_dump(realpath(".")); returns as expected (inside the test dir of the project). It should not matter though, because i tried the absolute path also?

Comment: yes, that part is puzzling :/... as an alternative, have you considered mocking the file system? I quite often use https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream in my tests, maybe this helps..?

Comment: thanks, i will look into that - did you ever succeed using file tests natively in phpunit?

Comment: Yes, never had a problem with it really... A few times (when i didn't use vfsStream) I had a folder with test assets which I passed as a parameter to the class I was testing, and it usually worked...Didn't use opendir much though, I tended to use scandir, but that should not make a difference....

Comment: vfsStream seems to have no support for opendir - worked around it by not using opendir now.